# How can the "select inputs" DataTables solution be modified to allow a select input to be deselected?

Tags: javascript, datatables

1. [select inputs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)
2. [text inputs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

These two DataTables filters provide the same functionality.  For example, in the first column when you search for "Angelica Ramos"  you get the single record for Angelica Ramos.

However, for the solution with select inputs, if "" (none) is selected after filtering for "Angelica Ramos" there are "No matching records found".

In the solution with text inputs, when the text is deleted the functionality works as desired.

How can the "select inputs" DataTables solution be modified to allow a select input to be deselected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways you could work around this solution, all done in the event handler function:

1) Remove the regex option for the column search, and instead use the smart search that they have built for you.

```
.on('change', function() {
    table.column(i)
    .search($(this).val()) // Uses default smart search
    .draw();
```

2) Add in an if-else statement to check for a blank string ("") value.

```
.on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        // Uses default smart search in only this case
        table.column(i).search('').draw();
    } else {
        // Uses regex search - this is what is shown on the select inputs page
        table.column(i).search('^'+$(this).val()+'$', true, false).draw();
```

Here is a JSFiddle with both of these options implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/gk5zB/5/

One of the options in the JSFiddle is commented out, but they both work. I hope that one of these solutions fits your needs.

Comment: Very glad that I could be of assistance. :)

Comment: i got an error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined", could you please help